# Python - convert date string from YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MMM-YYYY using datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

So I have read a number of threads on this, and am still stumped. Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

I have a column in a dataframe that contains strings of dates, or nothing.  Strings are in this format: `2017-10-17`, i.e. `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I want to convert these to `DD-MMM-YYYY`, so the above would read `17-Oct-2017`.

Here is the code that I have, which seems to do nothing.  It doesn't error out, but it doesn't actually modify the dates; they are the same as before. I'm calling this in the beginning: `import datetime`

```
df_combined['VisitDate'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y') if x != "" else "")
```

I expected this to return a string in a different format than the format the original string was in when it's read from the column.

Comment: Maybe `apply` just calls the function, but doesn't change the sequence. Look for some sort of `map` function.

Comment: What is this column and dataframe? SQL? Framework? The lambda works.

Comment: @DonchoGunchev it's "pandas" - the OP appears to have missed applying the tag to their question.

Answer (score 5):

You probably just need to assign the result back to the column itself:

```
df_combined['VisitDate'] = df_combined['VisitDate'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%d-%b-%Y') if x != "" else "")
```

Comment: Yep.  That was the next thing I tried, I thought of it when I was typing this up. I ought to write more questions and then not post them :)  Actually I need to learn when to assign and when to just apply.

Comment: Yes, `.apply` returns a *new* `Series`... However, `df_combined['VisitDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_combined.VisitDate).dt.strftime('%d-%B-%Y')` would be preferable when using pandas.

Comment: How to convert date from `20-09-2018` to `20th September 2018`? More specifically I want to know is there any way to add postfix like `th` with date?

Answer (score 2):

No need `apply` by using `pd.to_datetime`

```
pd.to_datetime(df_combined['VisitDate'],errors='coerce',format='%d-%b-%Y').fillna('')
```